# PnP PowerShell - how to load all properties of a ClientObject?

Tags: list, csom, pnp

Given a PnP cmdlet such as Get-PnPList there're a bunch of properties available but they're not populated upon executing the cmdlet. I'm looking for a way to load all of them, in a single call.

I know you can do `Get-PnPList -Identity [list] -Includes [Properties you want to load]`.
However, I've not found a way to load all of them at once.

I've tried gathering all possible properties in a variable using it for the `-Includes` parameter like so:

`$props = Get-PnPList | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Select-Object Name -ExpandProperty Name
Get-PnPList -Identity [list ]-Includes $props`

Unfortunately, I'm getting `Get-PnPList : The query expression 'Param_0.Context' 
is not supported.`

Now, I suspect this error springs from the `Context` property but is there're a way to achieve what I'm trying to?

Thanks.